# topology for engineers: closed, open, and bounded sets

Tags: general-topology

I have a question, from an engineers point of view (my apologies, rough on the math).  From what I have gathered from questions on topology here, considering sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$:

- a closed set has (and includes) a boundary
- an open set may (or may not) have a boundary. If so, doesn't include that boundary
- a bounded domain fits in a ball, and it could be open or closed

Are these *dumbed down* explanations close to correct?

Comment: Roughly speaking this is right. More precisely, one can formally define what the boundary of an arbitrary subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is. $S$ is then closed if and only if it includes its boundary and open if and only if it does contains no points of its boundary.

Comment: And bear in mind that there are even sets that are open *and* closed. $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ for one, but if you are looking at $\mathbb R$ with holes, there are more examples. Think of where $\frac 1{x^2-1}$ is defined. Excluding $\pm 1$ makes $(-1,+1)$ open *and* closed.

Comment: And, a bounded set need neither be open nor closed. Think of $(0,1]$. And there are far worse examples.

Comment: wait, Gyro Gearloose, is that example not just closed?  It includes a boundary, so that would contradict my first statement.

Comment: For $\mathbb R\setminus \{-1,+1\}$ $(-1,+1)=\bigcup_{1>\epsilon>0}(-1+\epsilon,+1-\epsilon)$. As arbitrary unions of open sets are open, this is open.

Comment: ok i think I see, $(0,1]$ includes some, but not all of its boundary.  Just to check then, $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq0\}$ is closed?

Comment: Yes $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\geq0\}$ is closed, by (strongest, as most immediate argument to the axioms) $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x\lt0\}$ as its complement, is open.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces&oldid=593544473#Definition_via_open_sets on how to define a specific topology by way of stating an initial (power-)set of open sets and the rules which sets then are implicitly *open* sets.

Comment: And probably you would take profit looking into the definitions of the interior, the closure and the boundary of any arbitrary set.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ always has a boundary **which might be empty**.

The boundary of a closed set can be empty. In particular, this is the case for $\mathbb{R}^d$ itself.

And you're right a bounded domain $S$ is included in a ball (by definition). Such a ball can be chosen open or closed as $$S \subset B(a,R) \Rightarrow S \subset \overline{B}(a,R)$$ and $$S \subset \overline{B}(a,R) \Rightarrow S \subset B(a,R+1)$$

Comment: ok i didn't think of an empty boundary. that is a useful detail.